# Least-square solutions for augmented inconsistent linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two inconsistent linear systems:
$$ Ax = b,$$ and $$ Cx = d,$$
where $$A, C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \ m > n.$$ We can assume that $A$ and $C$ are full rank.
Hence, we can get the least-square solutions $$x_A = A^+ b,$$ and $$x_C = C^+ d,$$ as well as compute the residual or error terms.

Now, consider the augmented linear (inconsistent) system $$Ex = f,$$

where
$$
   E=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   A \\
   C \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and

$$
   f=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   b \\
   d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Again, for this system, we can compute the least-square solution, $$x_E = E^+ f.$$

I am interested in finding:

- a closed-form relation between $E^+$ and $A^+$ and $C^+.$
- a closed-form relation between $x_A$ and $x_C$ and $x_E.$
- a closed-form relation between the residuals as well.

I have looked into the Generalized Inverses book by Ben-Israel and Greville but I only found the case for common solution for consistent linear systems.

Any reference appreciated.

NOTE: $A$ and $C$ above have a special structure but I will leave it out for now

Comment: You use $C$, then start talking about $D$, then return to $C$. Please settle your notation.

Comment: I edited the post. I think notation is fixed